# Find the curve of a family of curves with the following conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

> Let $\mathfrak{J}$ be the family of curves such that their normal line at each point is tangent to the parabola of equation $$y=kx^2$$ that passes through that point. Find the curve $C\in\mathfrak{J}$ that passes through $(0,1)$.

---

My work: $$\mathfrak{J}\colon y=kx^2\to k=\frac{y}{x^2},\quad y'=2kx=2\frac{y}{x^2}x=2\frac{y}{x}.$$ Moreover, $$\mathfrak{J}^\perp\colon -\frac{1}{y'}=2\frac{y}{x}\to-\frac x2=yy'\to\frac{y^2}2=-x^2+c\to y^2=-2x^2+C.$$ Since $y(0)=1$, we have that $1=C$, so the final answer is $$\boxed{y^2=-2x^2+1}$$

**Is it correct?**

The answer does not match with the book, the answer should be:

> $x^2+2y^2=2$.

Comment: You are almost there. This is not correct $\frac{y^2}2=-x^2+c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your attempt is correct:
$$yy'=-\frac x 2$$ 
Then you have :
$$ 2yy'=-x  \implies (y^2)'=-x$$
Integrate:
$$y^2=-\frac {x^2}2+c$$
$$2y^2+ {x^2}=2c$$
$$2y^2+ {x^2}=2$$